# How to install .Net framework for running Windows applications?

Tags: windows, wine, dotnet

I want to install a **Windows** application which runs on **.Net** framework.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu ? through [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/what-is-wine) ? running a [virtual machine](http://www.howtogeek.com/196060/beginner-geek-how-to-create-and-use-virtual-machines/) ? we can't help you with out more details !

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), which allows .NET applications to be run cross-platform, including on Linux.  It's not perfect and it doesn't cover all aspects of .NET, but many applications work fine on it.